# Getting invalid parameter marker on db2 query with additional bound value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, db2

I have a php script where I'm executing some PDO statements and everything's been working until now.

I recently added the `sg.group_code as group_code` into my first select, binding it as one of my values and using it in another select but the problem is, I'm now getting an error that "Use of parameter marker of NULL not valid"

Now if I remove the group_code form my first select, the bound values and the 2nd select, then it works fine. Also, running my 2nd select manually with values works fine.

What am I doing wrong by adding this one value?

```
<?php

$selectPlacements = "
    SELECT DISTINCT
        sku_id, s.frame as frame, sg.group_code as group_code, s.cover1 as cover, s.color1 as color, dealer_id
    FROM placements p
    inner join skus s 
    on p.sku_id = s.id
    inner join sku_groups sg 
    on sg.id = s.sku_group_id
    where p.expire_date > curdate()
    limit 100
    ;
";

try {
    $placementCheck = $MysqlConn->prepare($selectPlacements);
    $detailRslt = $placementCheck->execute();

     while ($placementRow = $placementCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        print_r($placementRow); //This prints the array I need that gets the parameters below

        $salesValues = [
        ":dealer_id" => $placementRow["dealer_id"],
        ":frame" => $placementRow["frame"],
        ":cover" => $placementRow["cover"],
        ":color" => $placementRow["color"],
        "group_code" => $placementRow["group_code"],
        ];



        $checkSales = "
            SELECT
                count(*) as sales_180,
                180/count(*) as velocity,
                :group_code,
                c.xslsno as salesNum,
                cr.slsupr as VP

            FROM groupSales g
                inner join customers c
                    on g.cstnoc = c.xcstno

                inner join customerReports cr
                    on c.xslsno = cr.xslsno
            WHERE g.cstnoc = :dealer_id
                AND g.framec = :frame
                AND g.covr1c = :cover
                AND g.colr1c = :color
                AND date(substr(g.extd1d,1,4)||'-'||substr(g.EXTD1d,5,2)||'-'||substr(g.EXTD1d,7,2) ) between current_Date - 180 DAY AND current_Date
                GROUP BY c.xslsno, cr.slsupr
        ";

        try{    
            $salesCheck = $DB2conn->prepare($checkSales);
            $salesResult = $salesCheck->execute($salesValues);


        }catch(PDOException $ex) {
            echo "QUERY TWO FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage(); 
        }
    }

}catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "QUERY ONE FAILED!: " .$ex->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Try casting it to the correct type

Comment: Should I cast it in the query itself? Or in the values I'm creating beforehand

Comment: In the query itself  `CAST(:group_code AS VARCHAR(32))`

Comment: db2? mysql?  which one? please [edit] your question to remove one of those tags.

Comment: @PaulVernon thank you that seemed to solve it!

Comment: @O.Jones I put both becuase my original select is from MySQL but the second is in DB2 so i wanted to make sure it wasn't stemming from an issue in MySQL